BaseModel.model_dump_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialize_as_any'
I use pydantic 2.5.3.
Here my code
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
    a: float = 0.0

When I do
a = A()
a.model_dump_json(serialize_as_any = True)

I got an error
        a = A()
>       a.model_dump_json(serialize_as_any = False)
E       TypeError: BaseModel.model_dump_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialize_as_any'

but according documentation it should work
Maybe I miss something?

It's not available in version 2.5 but available in latest versions

Updates to 2.7, all fine
